# Yii2 querybuilder sum from a one-many relation field

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2, query-builder

Help me understand how the sum function works, when I want to count from a relational table field.

The query is pretty simple. I have unitsOrdered table and unitsSent table. The relation is 1-n. So i want to count all sent units of the specific order. In this example order `id=2`;

In my db I have data.

unitsOrdered:

```
id
1
2
```

unitsSent:

```
id | order_id | units
1  |     1    |   5
2  |     2    |   2
```

My query is:

```
query = OrderedUnits::find()
                ->select([
                    'ou.*',
                    'sum(us.units) as alreadySent'
                ])
                ->joinWith('unitsSent us')
                ->where(['ou.id' => 2])
                ->orderBy('ou.id desc')
                ->groupBy(['ou.id'])
                ->all();
```

The result should be pretty clear:

```
id 2 = 2 units
```

However, my query returns:

```
id 2 = 10 units.
```

As I understand what i does is 5 * 2 = 10;

What is wrong with my query?

The relation is defined like this:

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getUnitsSent()
{
    return $this->hasMany(UnitsSent::className(), ['order_id' => 'id'])
        ->from(['us' => UnitsSent::tableName()]);
}
```

Actual query:

```
 'SELECT `ou`.*, sum(us.sent_units) as alreadySent FROM `ordered_units` `ou`
 LEFT JOIN `units_sent` `us` ON `ou`.`id` = `us`.`order_id`
 WHERE  (`ou`.`id`= 2)
 GROUP BY `ou`.`id`
 ORDER BY `ou`.`id` DESC'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the hash filter format this way   `->where(['us.id' => 2])`

and  for get result 2 you need  innerJoin (your raw sql show you have a left join) otherwise also the rows that not match are joined

```
query = OrderedUnits::find()
            ->select([
                'ou.*',
                'sum(us.units) as alreadySent'
            ])
            ->innerJoinWith('unitsSent us')
            ->where(['us.id' => 2])
            ->orderBy('ou.id desc')
            ->groupBy(['ou.id'])
            ->all();
```

and try check the real query executed using

```
echo $query->createCommand()->getRawSql();
```

*and remeber that the selection of columns not aggregated  and not mentioned in group by is not allowed  in mysql starting for 5.7  ( and anyway is not a correct way to use group by in SQL)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the where filter was a typo its fixed now but it didnt help.

Comment: Answer  updated with a suggestion for check the real query

Comment: updated my question with raw sql.. It looks fine to me. The thing is, if i dump  the object and do $object->unitsOrdered. ir returns the right relation(not both). I dont understand why does it multiply them then